# Why is no data showing out from my database using two Choice Fields?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

My project's purpose is to get data out of the database and only show it on the template. However, it is not showing anything.
There are two Choice Fields that determine what data to retrieve from the database. One for topics and one for question type.

This is the model.py that I am using:

```
        from django.db import models
        from home.choices import *

        # Create your models here.

        class Topic(models.Model):
            topic_name = models.IntegerField(
                            choices = question_topic_name_choices, default = 1)
            def __str__(self):
                return '%s' % self.topic_name

        class Image (models.Model):
            image_file = models.ImageField()

            def __str__(self):
                return '%s' % self.image_file

        class Question(models.Model):
            question_type = models. IntegerField(
                            choices = questions_type_choices, default = 1)
            question_topic = models.ForeignKey(    'Topic',
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                            blank=True,
                                            null=True)
            question_description = models.TextField()
            question_answer = models.ForeignKey(    'Answer',
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                            blank=True,
                                            null=True)
            question_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                            blank=True,
                                            null=True)

            def __str__(self):
                return '%s' % self.question_type

        class Answer(models.Model):
            answer_description = models.TextField()
            answer_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                            blank=True,
                                            null=True)
            answer_topic = models.ForeignKey(    'Topic',
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                            blank=True,
                                            null=True)
            def __str__(self):
                return '%s' % self.answer_description
```

This is the forms.py

```
        from django import forms
        from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
        from .models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
        from .choices import questions_type_choices, question_topic_name_choices

        class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
            topic_name      =   forms.ChoiceField(
                            choices=question_topic_name_choices,
                            widget = forms.Select(
                            attrs = {'class': 'home-select-one'}
                                ))

            class Meta:
                model = Topic
                fields = ['topic_name',]
                def __str__(self):
                    return self.fields


        class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
            question_type =   forms.ChoiceField(
                            choices= questions_type_choices,
                            widget = forms.Select(
                            attrs = {'class': 'home-select-two'},
                                ))
            question_answer = forms.CharField(
                            max_length=50,
                            widget  = forms.HiddenInput()
                                )
            question_image = forms.CharField(
                            max_length=50,
                            widget  = forms.HiddenInput()
                                )
            question_description = forms.CharField(
                            max_length=50,
                            widget  = forms.HiddenInput()
                                )
            class Meta:
                model = Question
                fields = ['question_type', 'question_description', 'question_answer', 'question_image']
                def __str__(self):
                    return self.fields


        class QuizMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
            form_classes    =   {
                        'topics':TopicForm,
                        'questions':QuestionForm
            }
            def save(self, commit=True):
                objects = super(QuizMultiForm, self).save(commit=False)

                if commit:
                    topic_name = objects['topic_name']
                    topic_name.save()
                    question_type = objects['question_type']
                    question_type.topic_name = topic_name
                    question_type.save()
                return objects
```

This is the views.py

```
        from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
        from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView
        from home.models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
        from home.forms import QuizMultiForm



        class QuizView(TemplateView):
            template_name = 'index.html'
            def get(self, request):
                form = QuizMultiForm()
                return render (request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

            def post(self, request):
                topic_name = ""
                question_type = ""
                question_description = ""
                question_answer = ""
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    form = QuizMultiForm(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        topic_name = form.cleaned_data['topics']['topic_name']
                        question_type = form.cleaned_data['questions']['question_type']
                        question_description = form.cleaned_data['questions']['question_description']
                        question_answer = form.cleaned_data['questions']['question_answer']
                    args = {'form': form, 'topic_name': topic_name, 'question_type': question_type, 'question_description': question_description, 'question_answer': question_answer}
                return render (request, 'results.html', args)
```

Thi is the HTML file

```html
  {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Topic Number : # {{ topic_name }}</th>
                  <th>Question Type: {{ question_type }}</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>The Question:{{ question_description }}</td>
                    <td>The Answer:{{ question_answer }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <!-- <td>The Question Image: {{ question_image }}</td> -->
                  <!-- <td>The Answer Image:{{ answer_image }}</td> -->
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
      {% endblock content %}
```

This is the choices.py

```
        question_topic_name_choices = (
            (1, "Topic #1: Measurements and Uncertainties"),
            (2, "Topic #2: Mechanics"),
            (3, "Topic #3: Thermal Physics"),
            (4, "Topic #4: Waves"),
            (5, "Topic #5: Electricity and Magnetism"),
            (6, "Topic #6: Circular Motion and Gravitation"),
            (7, "Topic #7: Atomic, Nuclear and Particle Physics"),
            (8, "Topic #8: Energy Production"),
            (9, "Topic #9: Wave Phenomena (HL Only)"),
            (10, "Topic #10: Fields (HL Only)"),
            (11, "Topic #11: Electromagnetic Induction (HL Only)"),
            (12, "Topic #12: Quantum and Nuclear Physics (HL Only)"),
            (13, "Option A: Relativity"),
            (14, "Option B: Engineering Physics"),
            (15, "Option C: Imaging"),
            (16, "Option D: Astrophysics")
                )

        questions_type_choices = (
            (1, "Multiple Choice Questions"),
            (2, "Problem Solving Questions"))
```

Comment: You don't need to add field again at forms.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add fields again at forms.py.  Here is a simple example of your task. here the model

```
#your choices
question_topic_name_choices = (
            (1, "Topic #1: Measurements and Uncertainties"),
            (2, "Topic #2: Mechanics"),
            (3, "Topic #3: Thermal Physics"),
            (4, "Topic #4: Waves"),
            (5, "Topic #5: Electricity and Magnetism"),
            (6, "Topic #6: Circular Motion and Gravitation"),
            (7, "Topic #7: Atomic, Nuclear and Particle Physics"),
            (8, "Topic #8: Energy Production"),
            (9, "Topic #9: Wave Phenomena (HL Only)"),
            (10, "Topic #10: Fields (HL Only)"),
            (11, "Topic #11: Electromagnetic Induction (HL Only)"),
            (12, "Topic #12: Quantum and Nuclear Physics (HL Only)"),
            (13, "Option A: Relativity"),
            (14, "Option B: Engineering Physics"),
            (15, "Option C: Imaging"),
            (16, "Option D: Astrophysics")
                )

questions_type_choices = (
            (1, "Multiple Choice Questions"),
            (2, "Problem Solving Questions"))
```

## Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from home.choices import *

        # Create your models here.

    class Topic(models.Model):
        topic_name = models.IntegerField(
                            choices = question_topic_name_choices, default = 1)
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % self.topic_name

    class Image (models.Model):
        image_file = models.ImageField()

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % self.image_file

    class Question(models.Model):
        question_type = models. IntegerField(
                            choices = questions_type_choices, default = 1)
        question_topic = models.ForeignKey(    'Topic',
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                            blank=True,
                                            null=True)
        question_description = models.TextField()
        question_answer = models.ForeignKey(    'Answer',
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                            blank=True,
                                            null=True)
        question_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                            blank=True,
                                            null=True)

        def __str__(self):

            return '%s' % self.question_type
```

Your forms

```
#forms.py
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ('topic_name',)
```

Now import your forms into views.py then pass it to template

from app.forms import TopicForm

```
#views.py
def loadTopic(request):

    form=TopicForm()
    return render(request,'template.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: What about my views? How would I view this on the template? And can I just apply this on my already existing model?

Comment: include this form in view.py file and pass it to view. If you dnt have idea then please response. i will help you out.

Comment: To be honest with you, I Have no idea how to apply what you have coded on my project.

Comment: Let write a whole flow of django with some explanation for you. Don't worry you will understand.

Comment: I don’t know what to say. Thank you. I will do my best to understand and learn what you will teach me.

Comment: Hello sir, I would like to remind you of my problem. Could you please see if you can help me or not.

Comment: Sorry for your time i totally forgot about it. I am on it now.

Comment: I am truly sorry, I am aware that it is me who is asking a question and should wait for your answer as long as it takes, but my deadline was this Friday and you don't find it as an insult but "Hope is a Dangerous Thing. Hope Can Drive a Man Insane."

Comment: I am so sorry for inconvenience .Please have an eye on it.

Comment: @MajedSaaeddin check it.\

Comment: I am the one who is Sorry, why the inconvenience, you are somehow saving my life. I was just trying to remind you in a polite and new way and because I like the quote and would like to use it. I am truly thankful :) AndI did a mistake in my typing up there. What I meant was, "I hope you don't find it as an insult."